# GMail API getting Access Not Configured in Android

Tags: android, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-oauth-java-client, android-googleapiclient

Hi i am trying to implement GMail API in my android app to send mail in background. But i am getting a response like this. Even if I enabled Gmail API permission in my app.

```
{
      "code" : 403,
      "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "usageLimits",
        "message" : "Access Not Configured. The API (Gmail API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
        "reason" : "accessNotConfigured",
        "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com"
      } ],
      "message" : "Access Not Configured. The API (Gmail API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
    }
```

I followed https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android for integrating.

Comment: Access Not Configured. The API (Gmail API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.

Have you checked in your google console?

Comment: Did you get the screen for the app to request access to google(google Auth 2)

Comment: @psy Yes i did. I gave the email id and fetch a list of Gmail labels attached to the specified account its showing this.

Comment: @Just I checked the console. Its enabled.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem here. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @JohnYang If you get the answer please let me know.

Comment: @Nivedh, Actually I got it working. One thing I did is just to compile with release configuration instead of debug. (i.e. signed apk). Or maybe it just takes few minutes for the server to set everything up correctly. And you have to make sure your SHA1 thing is correct on developer console.

Comment: So if you are using the debug key, you have to use the relative SHA1 or if you use your own key, you have to build with release with correct SHA1 entered in developer console.